# Avoid importing non-alphanumeric characters using textscan but keeping minus signs

Tags: matlab

I have a file with a row like this:

2015 02 18 08 00 00.067 @D,+000.00,-000.05,+000.00,M,+335.61,00,@22

So i've tried the following:

```
 fileID = fopen('150218_120000.00.10m');
       data = textscan(fileID, '%f%f%f%f%f%f%c%f%f%f%c%f%f%f%c%s', 'headerLines', 1, 'delimiter',',' );

 fclose(fileID);
```

Is the following possible? I.e. keeping negative signs but no other non-alphanumeric characters?

2015 02 18 08 00 00.067 D 000.00 -000.05 000.00 M 335.61 00 22

**EDIT:**

The desired output is that each value separated by a space take up a single cell.
i.e. 2015 | 02 | 18 | 08 | etc

**EDIT 2:** More data

```
2015 02 18 13 00 00.067 D,-000.19,+000.35,-000.54,M,+341.28,00,26
2015 02 18 13 00 00.167 D,-000.34,+000.27,-000.27,M,+341.51,00,20
2015 02 18 13 00 00.267 D,-000.03,+000.21,-000.01,M,+341.48,00,2E
2015 02 18 13 00 00.367 D,+000.00,-000.14,-000.09,M,+341.36,00,2A
2015 02 18 13 00 00.467 D,+000.11,+000.27,-000.20,M,+341.44,00,22
2015 02 18 13 00 00.567 D,+000.05,+000.64,-000.23,M,+341.49,00,2E
```

Comment: What would the output be? A string with non-alphanumeric charcters removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer to original question

- The file can contain several lines.
- The desired output is a string for each line of the file.

You can do it as follows. The result `s` is cell array of strings, each corresponding to a line of the original file.

```
s = importdata('file.txt'); %// read each file's line into a cell
s = regexprep(s, '[^\w\.-\s]', ' '); %// replaced unwanted characters by space
s = regexprep(s, '\s+', ' '); %// convert multiple spaces into single spaces
```

### Answer to edited question

The file contains several lines. Each line should be split into substrings. Splliting characters are space or comma. I assume all lines in the file have the same structure (will give the same number of substrings):

```
s = importdata('file.txt', ''); %// read each line into a cell
s = regexp(s, '[\s,]', 'split'); %// split at space or comma. Cell array of cell arrays
s = vertcat(s{:});
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer. I'd like the values to occupy individual cells if possible.

Comment: @HCAI you can split at the spaces with `regexp`: `s = regexp(s, ' ', 'split');`

Comment: Looks good!  @excaza Each row is now in an individual cell. Can we put each data point into an array? i.e. it would be of size=rows x 12?

Comment: Thank you @excaza and Luis Mendo. Very helpful indeed!

Comment: I think I've made a mistake somewhere. The data that comes out is in a cell... So if I look at s{1,8}='000.00' which is a string right? So if i want to do s{:,8}.^2 I get Error using  .^ 
Too many input arguments. Is there a way to put the numerical values into an array so that I can perform operations on it?

Comment: I'm finding that s = vertcat(s{:}); is not working for me now, giving a dimension error. All cells are <1x14cell>. Currently before vertcat command: s{1,1}

ans = 

  Columns 1 through 6

    '2015'    '02'    '18'    '13'    '00'    '00.067'

  Columns 7 through 11

    'D'    '-000.19'    '000.35'    '-000.54'    'M'

  Columns 12 through 14

    '341.28'    '00'    '26'

Comment: The following seems to fix it, but it's very cumbersome no? [r c]=size(s);
mat=ones(size(s));
for i=1:r
    for j=1:c
mat(i,j)=str2double(s{i,j});
    end
end

Comment: @HCAI I find it hard to understand what you want. You say you want to split based on space, but I think you also want to split based on comma. See my edited answer